# Finding repetitions of values and changing the value of some other cell based on the result of search in VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I have an Excel file which I want to write a VBA code for. I want to check the values in a specific column and if some value has more than one occurrences, the value of all related rows in some other column will be summed up and set for themselves.

Let me bring you an example. I have a worksheet like this:

[image]

I check column `"C"`. There are 3 occurrences of `0` in rows 1, 4 and 6. I sum up the value of `"B1"`, `"B4"` and `"B6"`, which will be `444 + 43434 + 43434 = 87312` and set this summation for the same columns, i.e. all `"B1"`, `"B4"` and `"B6"` cells will have the value `87312`.

I have found a code for finding all occurrences of some value and with some change it fits my problem; but I can't find related cells on the other column. This is the code I use:

```
Sub FindRepetitions()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim FindWhat As Variant
    Dim FoundCells As Range
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim Summation As Integer
    Dim ColNumber As Integer
    Dim RelatedCells As Range

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set SearchRange = ws.Range("C1:C" & lastRow)

    For Each NewCell In SearchRange
        FindWhat = NewCell.Value
        Set FoundCells = FindAll(SearchRange:=SearchRange, _
                            FindWhat:=FindWhat, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            BeginsWith:=vbNullString, _
                            EndsWith:=vbNullString, _
                            BeginEndCompare:=vbTextCompare)

        If FoundCells.Count > 1 Then
            ' 2 is the Number of letter B in alphabet '
            ColNumber = 2
            For i = 1 To FoundCells.Count
                Set RelatedCells(i) = ws.Cells(FoundCells(i).Row, ColNumber)
            Next
            Set Summation = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(RelatedCells)
            For Each RelatedCell In RelatedCells
                Set Cells(RelatedCell.Row, RelatedCell.Column).Value = Summation
            Next RelatedCell
        End If

    Next

End Sub



Function FindAll(SearchRange As Range, _
                FindWhat As Variant, _
                Optional LookIn As XlFindLookIn = xlValues, _
                Optional LookAt As XlLookAt = xlWhole, _
                Optional SearchOrder As XlSearchOrder = xlByRows, _
                Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False, _
                Optional BeginsWith As String = vbNullString, _
                Optional EndsWith As String = vbNullString, _
                Optional BeginEndCompare As VbCompareMethod = vbTextCompare) As Range
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' FindAll
    ' This searches the range specified by SearchRange and returns a Range object
    ' that contains all the cells in which FindWhat was found. The search parameters to
    ' this function have the same meaning and effect as they do with the
    ' Range.Find method. If the value was not found, the function return Nothing. If
    ' BeginsWith is not an empty string, only those cells that begin with BeginWith
    ' are included in the result. If EndsWith is not an empty string, only those cells
    ' that end with EndsWith are included in the result. Note that if a cell contains
    ' a single word that matches either BeginsWith or EndsWith, it is included in the
    ' result.  If BeginsWith or EndsWith is not an empty string, the LookAt parameter
    ' is automatically changed to xlPart. The tests for BeginsWith and EndsWith may be
    ' case-sensitive by setting BeginEndCompare to vbBinaryCompare. For case-insensitive
    ' comparisons, set BeginEndCompare to vbTextCompare. If this parameter is omitted,
    ' it defaults to vbTextCompare. The comparisons for BeginsWith and EndsWith are
    ' in an OR relationship. That is, if both BeginsWith and EndsWith are provided,
    ' a match if found if the text begins with BeginsWith OR the text ends with EndsWith.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim FirstFound As Range
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Dim ResultRange As Range
    Dim XLookAt As XlLookAt
    Dim Include As Boolean
    Dim CompMode As VbCompareMethod
    Dim Area As Range
    Dim MaxRow As Long
    Dim MaxCol As Long
    Dim BeginB As Boolean
    Dim EndB As Boolean


    CompMode = BeginEndCompare
    If BeginsWith <> vbNullString Or EndsWith <> vbNullString Then
        XLookAt = xlPart
    Else
        XLookAt = LookAt
    End If

    ' this loop in Areas is to find the last cell
    ' of all the areas. That is, the cell whose row
    ' and column are greater than or equal to any cell
    ' in any Area.

    For Each Area In SearchRange.Areas
        With Area
            If .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row > MaxRow Then
                MaxRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
            End If
            If .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column > MaxCol Then
                MaxCol = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column
            End If
        End With
    Next Area
    Set LastCell = SearchRange.Worksheet.Cells(MaxRow, MaxCol)

    On Error GoTo 0
    Set FoundCell = SearchRange.Find(what:=FindWhat, _
            after:=LastCell, _
            LookIn:=LookIn, _
            LookAt:=XLookAt, _
            SearchOrder:=SearchOrder, _
            MatchCase:=MatchCase)

    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        Set FirstFound = FoundCell
        Do Until False ' Loop forever. We'll "Exit Do" when necessary.
            Include = False
            If BeginsWith = vbNullString And EndsWith = vbNullString Then
                Include = True
            Else
                If BeginsWith <> vbNullString Then
                    If StrComp(Left(FoundCell.Text, Len(BeginsWith)), BeginsWith, BeginEndCompare) = 0 Then
                        Include = True
                    End If
                End If
                If EndsWith <> vbNullString Then
                    If StrComp(Right(FoundCell.Text, Len(EndsWith)), EndsWith, BeginEndCompare) = 0 Then
                        Include = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            If Include = True Then
                If ResultRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set ResultRange = FoundCell
                Else
                    Set ResultRange = Application.Union(ResultRange, FoundCell)
                End If
            End If
            Set FoundCell = SearchRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
            If (FoundCell Is Nothing) Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            If (FoundCell.Address = FirstFound.Address) Then
                Exit Do
            End If

        Loop
    End If

    Set FindAll = ResultRange

End Function
```

I get `Runtime Error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set` for this line:

```
Set RelatedCells(i) = ws.Cells(FoundCells(i).Row, ColNumber)
```

I removed the `Set` and got the same error. What is wrong?

Comment: You haven't set your RelatedCells reference before that - have you? If so RelatedCells(i) essentially stands for RelatedCells.item(i) I think - so you are trying to apply the Item method on an object that doesn't exist

Comment: I am confused. @_@ What are you trying to achieve? Btw, *FindAll* already do find all matches, why do you have to use another *For Each Loop*? So I think that is redundant. And what do you mean by `I sum up the value of "B1", "B4" and "B6" and set this summation for the same columns, i.e. "B1", "B4" and "B6"`? After summing the values what do you mean by setting them back to those ranges?

Comment: @IAmDranged, in line `Set RelatedCells(i) = ws.Cells(FoundCells(i).Row, ColNumber)`, I'm trying to set values for RelatedCells's items for the first time; should I set something beforehand or what? I'm not an expert VBA, so please explain more if you mind.

Comment: @L42, the loop `For i = 1 To FoundCells.Count` is trying to find the summation of RelatedCells; and I also explained about the summation in the question. The other loop `For Each RelatedCell In RelatedCells` is trying to set the summation for RelatedCells. If you can provide me some simpler way to do it, that'd be really great.

Comment: I did. See my post. If the way I understand your question is correct, that should do it. If there are parts you do not understand, comment it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment this should work:

```
Sub FindRepetitions()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, SearchRange As Range
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set SearchRange = ws.Range("C1:C" & lastRow)
    '~~> First determine the values that are repeated
    Dim repeated As Variant, r As Range
    For Each r In SearchRange
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SearchRange, r.Value) > 1 Then 
            If IsEmpty(repeated) Then
                repeated = Array(r.Value)
            Else
                If IsError(Application.Match(r.Value,repeated,0)) Then
                    ReDim Preserve repeated(Ubound(repeated) + 1)
                    repeated(Ubound(repeated)) = r.Value
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    '~~> Now use your FindAll function finding the ranges of repeated items
    Dim rep As Variant, FindWhat As Variant, FoundCells As Range
    Dim Summation As Long
    For Each rep In repeated
        FindWhat = rep
        Set FoundCells = FindAll(SearchRange:=SearchRange, _
                        FindWhat:=FindWhat, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        BeginsWith:=vbNullString, _
                        EndsWith:=vbNullString, _
                        BeginEndCompare:=vbTextCompare).Offset(0, -1)
        '~~> Take note that we use Offset to return Cells in B instead of C
        '~~> Sum FoundCells
        Summation = WorksheetFunction.Sum(FoundCells)
        '~~> Output in those ranges
        For Each r In FoundCells
            r = Summation
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Not tested. Also this assumes that *FindAll* function works perfectly.
Also I am not explicit on using *WorksheetFunction* but it should work as well. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use a sumif function.

The following code inserts a column (to prevent overwriting) uses a sumif function to calculate the value you want and then copies the values back into column B and erases the temporary column.

```
Sub temp()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Insert a column so nothing is overwritten
Range("E1").EntireColumn.Insert

'Assign formula
Range("E1").Formula = "=sumif(C:C,C1,B:B)"
Range("E1:E" & lastrow).FillDown

'copy value back into column B
Range("B1:B" & lastrow).Value = Range("E1:E" & lastrow).Value

'delete column
Range("E1").EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think if your code will work on my data. The cells which I want to sum are not together; neither the cells which I want to fill.

Comment: It works for the example you posted. Cells don't need to be together and if there is only one cell with a value sumif returns that value (and hence doesn't change anything).  Try running it on an example sheet and see if it gives what you need.  Better yet put the formula =sumif(C:C,C1,B:B) in a cell in row 1 copy down and see if that column gives the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an aside to reiterate and try and explain better what I point out in my comment re accessing a range by RelatedCells(i) where RelatedCells is a range object - this comes down to calling the Item method on the RelatedCells range object, so unless the RelatedCells object actually exists when doing so VBA will throw the type of error you are seeing, since you can't call a method on an object that doesn't exist

Another more litteral and maybe easier way to look at it is that by RelatedCells(i), you are trying to refer to the cell at the ith position:

- relative to a certain cell of reference
- offset from this cell of reference by a certain number of rows and columns

So you need to have some kind of reference that is set in the first place - which are all provided by the RelatedCells object:

- the first cell of this range will act as the cell of reference
- its shape - number of rows and columns - will determine the offset pattern

Hope that helps clarify a little